# Bad Request 400 - protocol error on a valid url - Webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to parse this page (http://www.coleparmer.co.uk/Product/Turb_Std_Hach_2100q_Kit/WZ-99900-47)
 using webclient and am having no luck.

```
 var client = new WebClient();
  var html = client.DownloadString("http://www.coleparmer.co.uk/Product/Turb_Std_Hach_2100q_Kit/WZ-99900-47");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The appropriate headers needs to be set.

```
try
{
    string html;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept", " text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
        html = client.DownloadString("http://www.coleparmer.co.uk/Product/Turb_Std_Hach_2100q_Kit/WZ-99900-47");
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && ex.Response != null)
    {
        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) // HTTP 404
        {
            //Handle it
        }
    }
    //Handle it
}
```

Comment: Not sure but why in many cases, just not having User-Agent gives Error 400 Bad Request. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

It requires a Header.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
```

Comment: I get same error after adding header mentioned in this answer.