# WebException (Status: Protocol Error)

Tags: c#, http, http-headers

I am calling a url in C# using `WebClient` class. Following is the code: -

```
    public string SendWebRequest(string requestUrl)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string responseText = client.DownloadString(requestUrl);
            return responseText;
        } 
    }
```

This code fails with following Exception details: -

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (1201).
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)

Exception Status: ProtocolError
```

URL hit the server properly. Actions expected (update database) on server happen properly. Server sends response properly. `WebClient` is not processing the response.

I also tried using `HttpWebRequest` class without success.

Initially, similar issue was there while request. It was resolved when I modified my `app.config` with following: -

```
    <settings>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true"/>
    </settings>
```

I cannot post URL on this forum and anyway it is not accessible outside network.

**If I copy same URL in browser address bar, it just works fine and returns expected response.**

What could be the problem with windows application then?

**Edit 1**

I implemented suggestions from answer. I also implemented suggestion in accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623664/bad-request-400-protocol-error-on-a-valid-url-webclient) question. Now, my function looks as follows: -

```
    public string SendWebRequest(string requestUrl)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
            client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
            string responseText = client.DownloadString(requestUrl);
            return responseText;
        } 
    }
```

It still does not solve the problem. Response is now blank string ("") instead of "Success". This is not fault from server which is confirmed.

If I remove configuration in `app.config`, it throws other exception.

```
System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
```

Comment: You need to send the appropiate request headers (`Accept` for instance), and any other header that the server may need (such as `User-Agent`)

Comment: problem is not on server. problem is on client side when it receives response, it is not able to parse it IMO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad Request 400 - protocol error on a valid url - Webclient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623664/bad-request-400-protocol-error-on-a-valid-url-webclient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is returning `HTTP 1201` which is not a [standard status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

`WebClient` will fail with an exception when facing a non-successful status code (or an unrecognized one, in your case).

I encorauge you to use the new [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) class if you can:

```
public async Task<string> SendWebRequest(string requestUrl)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl))
         return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

If you have to do it synchronously:

```
public string SendWebRequest(string requestUrl)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
         return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: I am doing this synchronously. I get following exception: - `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` on line `HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: @A_J Looks like an issue on the server, not the client. Client code is fine.

Comment: It's bad practice to dispose `HttpClient` please fix @MatiasCicero

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the headers of your webclient. It seems that your response is not compatible with the header types. 
I would suggest that you add an Accept header to your client `client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");` assuming that you are waiting for Json.

Comment: if you are returning plain text, then try `client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain");`

Comment: @A_J Can u check it with Fiddler, may be the problem is with your Http Response. If you can post here the response that Fiddler sees may be it would be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly from Fiddler you are asking. See if following is helpful; otherwise let me know. **RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
~headers~: 101
~???????~: 10
**

Comment: Response Header from Fiddler: -`HTTP/1.1 1201
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 10
Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 11:10:23 GMT

SUCCESS`

Comment: Response Auth: `No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.

No WWW-Authenticate Header is present.

`

Comment: @A_J Ok If you are just returning SUCCESS then why is your Content-Length:10 and not Content-Length:7. Also check the Content-Type in the response header on Fiddler whether it is has a charset sent with it. Something like Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8