# the remote server returned an error (400) bad request

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to generate data in XML Format by using a RSS feed URL. I got the exception:

> Remote server returned an error (400) bad request error.

I'm using a SSIS package and I created a Security Task in control Flow, the script I've written is as follows:

```
public bool DownloadFeed()
{
    string user = "xxx";
    string password = "pwd";

    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password);
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
                                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
                                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    wc.DownloadFile(@"https://Entered RSS Feed URL here", @"H:\import\Test.xml");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you try without System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

Comment: Hi. Yes i tried before i got The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. error. so i added System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol line in code

Comment: Possibly missing header; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623664/bad-request-400-protocol-error-on-a-valid-url-webclient

Comment: Thank you so much.. It is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the way the credentials are being formatted and passed to the server.
Can you try this?

```
using System.Net;

public bool DownloadFeed()
{
    string user = "xxx";
    string password = "pwd";

    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + ":" + password));
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =      System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
                                                    SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                                    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
                                                    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    wc.DownloadFile(@"https://Entered RSS Feed URL here", @"H:\import\Test.xml");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   got 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Headers' and no extension method 'Headers' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) at line                              wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;

Comment: As you are using the fully qualified name for the WebClient, I suspect that you may be missing a using directive. I have updated the code above to include the missing directive.

Comment: Thank you so much..Working fine