# C# Trying to download source of website but remote server returns 400

Tags: c#, .net

However much I searched I can't get it to work, I am trying to download https://soundcloud.com/ source but I keep getting the Bad Request error. I don't think the way I give the URL is the problem as it works with other websites like https://www.google.com or https://twitter.com/ and reddit.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

class PageDownloader
{   
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string site = "";
        string savedFile = $"\\Page.html";
        string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

        Console.WriteLine("Downloading Website Source...");

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        try {
        site = client.DownloadString("https://soundcloud.com/");
        } catch (WebException e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(desktopPath+savedFile, site);
        Console.WriteLine("\nDownload finished!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Is there any specific reason why I am unable to download soundclouds source code or is there a mistake in my code

Comment: It probably wants some headers.

Comment: A lot of the times when you get a `4xx` class error, the website will give you some indication of why that is, such as a validation response.  Try using a debugging proxy (like Fiddler) to see what the full request and response is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623664/bad-request-400-protocol-error-on-a-valid-url-webclient

Comment: It just requires an UserAgent Header, not even a specific TLS protocol. Just add `client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");`